# Can't build Twisted==20.3.0 on Linux using gcc 4.8.5

Tags: python, linux, gcc, twisted

I was trying to install Twisted on Python 3.8. I know Twisted doesn't support Python 3.8 yet, that's why `pip install` trying to build it from source. However the gcc on my Linux machine is at a lower version, and I don't want to upgrade it. Is there a way I can tell `pip` to use `gcc 4.8.5` to build twisted?

Here's the error I got directly from `pip install Twisted==20.3.0`

```
... ...
running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/twisted
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/twisted/test
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fno-semantic-interposition -fPIC -I/path/to/venv38/include -I/path/to/python3.8 -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/twisted/test/raiser.o
    gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-semantic-interposition’
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /path/to/venv38/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ovoof0ve/twisted/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ovoof0ve/twisted/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-3ftmx451/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /path.to/venv38/include/site/python3.8/Twisted Check the logs for full command output.
```

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
```

Answer (score -1):

GCC 5.3 has added a new option: -fno-semantic-interposition

Comment: I got that part. My question was can I build Twisted using GCC 4.8.5. I don't have the option to upgrade GCC.